# Ethers.js - Swap Event Listener - No Data Returned

Tags: ethereum, ethers.js

I am trying to set up an event listener for "Swap" events on BSC. I have followed the example on the Ethers docs, but I am not recieving any information back even though there are swap events being emitted (confirmed on BSCScan).

Can you tell me if I am doing something wrong?

```
const { ethers } = require("ethers");

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider('https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org')

const address = '0x16b9a82891338f9bA80E2D6970FddA79D1eb0daE' // BNB/USDT pair
const pairABI = [
    "function name() view returns (string)",
    "event Swap(address indexed sender, uint256 amount0In, uint256 amount1In, uint256 amount0Out, uint256 amount1Out, address indexed to)"
  ];
const contract = new ethers.Contract(address, pairABI, provider)

const main = async () => {
    const name = await contract.name()
    console.log(`\nListening for swap events for ${name}\n`)
    // Receive an event when ANY swap occurs
    contract.on("Swap", (sender, amount0In, amount1In, amount0Out, amount1Out, to, event) => {    
        console.log(sender);
    });
}

main()
```

I've followed the example on the Ethers.js guidance docs and also looked at a bunch of other examples and I seem to be doing the right thing, but getting nowhere.

Comment: Make sure that the event is correct. The variable names are case sensitive.

Comment: @Pandapip1 tried upper and lowercase, but still nothing returned. Upper is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a web socket provider, like so:

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider("wss://...");
```

Check official doc - https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/providers/other/#WebSocketProvider

Comment: The issue was the node I was using. Switched to the Anker node and it works fine.